# Xamarin iOS Release Build fails

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin iOS in Visual Studio 2017 for Windows!
Building and debugging the debug Version of my App via a build host works great. But when I try to build the Release Version it says:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3463,5): error MSB6006: "sgen.exe" exited with code 1.
```

Signing Identities are installed and vislible in VS.
I also found [this Blog post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93039/sgen-exe-exited-with-code-1). But the workaround is only for Mac Users.
Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured your iOS release? if not this may be the solution.

In Visual Studio, open Solution Explorer (Keyboard: Ctrl + Alt + L).

Right-click your solution and then click Configuration Manager.

On the configuration manager dialog box open the active solution configuration  drop-down menu and click New.

On the new solution configuration dialog box:

- For Name, enter iOS Release
- Open Copy settings from drop-down menu and select Release.
- Clear the Create new project configurations dialog box.

Open the Active solution platform drop-down menu:

- Select iPhoneSimulator and clear the check boxes on all rows except
  your Xamarin.iOS project and any projects (for example, portable class libraries) it depends on.
- Repeat this step for iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I will check that as soon as I can.